# How to identify request sent via Html.RenderAction()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, renderaction

In a project we use PartialView and View on the same action, depending how it is called (thanks to Request.IsAjaxRequest()). But there are places where we need to render an action on a page (not ajax).

So we use the HTML helper :

```
Html.RenderAction(Action, Controller, routeValues)
```

But this kind of call should also return a PartialView and not a View. And since this seems not to be an Ajax call, we can't use the Request.IsAjaxRequest() method to determine how the request has been sent.

I would like to know if there is something that we can use that could determine if the request has been made by a Html.RenderAction call ?

Comment: This not what I'm asking. I know I can make Ajax request, but I don't want to. all my ajax request are done via jQuery on top of normal request... Html.RenderAction is not done via Ajax.

Comment: or you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted...

Comment: I have to wait some times before I can answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by searching through the whole Request / Controller context and finally found the property [IsChildAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.ischildaction.aspx) on the [ControllerContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.aspx). This indicates if the action has been called via Html.RenderAction or via the URL.